# Deis deployment doesn't work with codeship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deis, codeship

I have a RoR app deployed on Deis and I'm trying to set up Codeship to automatically deploy on Deis.

here are the steps I've taken so far:

Register codeship account to deis:

```
deis register deis.example.com
username: codeship
password:
password confirmation:
```

Adding Codeship deployment key to deis:

```
deis keys:add <codeship_key_path>
```

In codeship deployment

```
git remote add deis <repo_url>
git push deis next:master
```

What happened is that repo on deis got updated but the app didn't got deployed.

Comment: Can you provide an error message?  Hard to troubleshoot without one..

Comment: @gabrtv the thing is codeship successfuly pushed to deis repo but this doesn't trigger deis deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same steps and they worked provided the new user you created was added to the DEIS project

`deis perms:create codeship`

The changes were pushed and the changed deployed to DEIS
If this doesn't work, make sure deploying via git to DEIS is working when logged in as your user locally.

Comment: oh, how such detail slipped my mind!!! .. works now after almost 9 months of using a workaround.